# jQuery strips tags from XML

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

I have a page which acts as an AJAX loader using jQuery.  It fetches XML documents, like this one, and inserts the values of `title`, `authPhrase` and `content` into appropriate `div`s in the displayed page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tinglePage>
  <title>Home</title>
  <authPhrase>welcome, Jashank<br /><a href="/tingle/auth/logout">logout</a></authPhrase>
  <content>
    <p>There are <strong>two</strong> types of folks who sit around
    thinking about how to kill people: <em>psychopaths</em> and
    <em>mystery writers</em>.  I'm the kind who pays better.</p>
  </content>
</tinglePage>
```

When I use this JavaScript, it strips out the tags from the inserted content.

```
    jQuery.get(path, {ajax: "true"}, function(xml) {
        document.title = "Tingle :: " + $("title", xml).text();
        $(".pageTitle").html(
            $("title", xml).text()
        );

        $(".authPhrase").html(
            $("authPhrase", xml).text()
        );

        $(".content").html(
            $("content", xml).text()
        );
    });
```

Is there some way to insert the XML into the displayed page without stripping content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the content with a CDATA block. This way when you use `.text()` you get whole content with html tags;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tinglePage>
  <title>Home</title>
  <authPhrase><![CDATA[welcome, Jashank<br /><a href="/tingle/auth/logout">logout</a>]]></authPhrase>
  <content>
    <![CDATA[<p>There are <strong>two</strong> types of folks who sit around
    thinking about how to kill people: <em>psychopaths</em> and
    <em>mystery writers</em>.  I'm the kind who pays better.</p>]]>
  </content>
</tinglePage>
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/xgnmT/).

Answer (score 0):

The .text() method returns only the characters (preserving spaces, and html entities) between html tags. the .html() method returns characters without any additional processing; if my memory serves me correctly :)

Comment: The jQuery documentation says that the `.html()` method "is not available on XML documents".  I've tried, and get error messages about a nonexistent `this.innerHTML`.

Comment: fudge, well I should have known you'd try that haha!